# WM_GESTURE - inertia values on Windows 8

Tags: windows, touch

Does anybody know about a difference in the inertia values between Windows 7 and Windows 8?

I'm using the same machine with both OSs, but get a totally different values on Windows 8, which affects the behavior of my application.

Just for the record, It's a regular win32 app, c++.